# Detect click on OS X menu bar?

Tags: macos, menubar, osx-lion, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I'm curious if there's a trick to detecting a click on the Menu Bar as a whole. I know I can detect a click on an NSStatusItem or NSMenu, but I am looking for events pertaining to the empty space of the Menu Bar.

Looking through the documentation, it does not seem possible. However, I wanted to know if anyone had a workaround for this functionality?

Comment: did you ever found a solution to fire an event on the empty space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a local event monitor using NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:

See the documentation located [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH15-SW3).

Comment: Whilst the content of this answer is true, it does not apply to the empty space of the menu bar, as asked by the OP